# Extracting a specific format substring (ID, code) from a string using R

Tags: r, string, twitter, substring

Suppose I have a data frame composed of tweets I harvested using twitteR. I want to extract a substring which is a unique ID for another data set, contained in each tweet. All IDs are of the same form, 3-4 uppercase letters, followed by a hyphen, and followed by a 6 digit number. Examples are: YLD-000123,YLSL-000323,YLP-000135. I only need the ID and can drop everything else on each tweet.

Here are two examples of the tweets I'm working with:

```
  st1="Elijo ENTERTIMER, YLC-000354, como ganador para  http://t.co/jclDk8d796 #YoungLionsCo #FantasyLions"
st2="Elijo #AEseTrenNoMeLeSubo, YLSL-000169, como ganador para  http://t.co/wPpM7X5ecN #YoungLionsCo #FantasyLions"
tweets=c(st1,st2)
```

The result I need is "YLC-000354" "YLSL-000169". The ID is not always between commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An approach using `gsub`:

```
gsub('.*[^[:alpha:]]([[:alpha:]]+-\\d+).*','\\1',tweets)
#[1] "YLC-000354"  "YLSL-000169"
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need *regular expressions*, see `?regex` for reference.

Pattern you are looking for is `'[[:alpha:]]{3,4}-[[:digit:]]{6}'` and eventually with `upper` instead of `alpha`, if only upper case letters are contained in IDs. Adding a space character before and period/space at end of pattern might be considered to eliminate some ID look-alikes.

To extract all all IDs from tweet vector I suggest using `str_extract` from `stringr` library.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('.*(\\b\\w+\\-\\d+).*','\\1',tweets)
# [1] "YLC-000354"  "YLSL-000169"
```